# How to automatically resize all tables to optimal column width in a docx with LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: docx, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

### Problem

I have 100+ *.docx files created with Microsoft Word on a Windows machine that I would like to use with LibreOffice Writer.
Unfortunately, somehow all the tables have been squished in Writer as shown:

[image: start table]

I've tried to fix this by:

1. Selecting the entire table (ctrl-a, ctrl-a)
2. Right-click the table
3. Go to `size`
4. Click `optimal column width`

This indeed gives me the desired result:
[image: desired table]

#### What I've tried so far

##### failed approach 1

I've created the following macro that does the formatting for a single table:

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

sub setTableColumns
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem define variables
dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem get access to the document
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:SelectAll", "", 0, Array())
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:SelectAll", "", 0, Array())
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:SetOptimalColumnWidth", "", 0, Array())


end sub
```

I've assigned a keyboard shortcut to this macro such that I can reformat a single table by:

1. Clicking on the table of interest.
2. Running the shortcut.

This is an improvement, but it still requires a lot of manual work.

##### failed approach 2

I've also tinkered with the examples given in this [different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605183/libreoffice-4-1-writer-macro-to-adjust-column-widths-in-tables).
I've managed to set the relative width of all tables to 100% by changing this property of all my tables:
https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/TextTable.html#RelativeWidth

I did this by using the following macro (snippet):

```
tables = ThisComponent.TextTables

for tid = 0 to tables.count - 1
    table = tables(tid)
    table.RelativeWidth  = 100
next
```

This does widen all the tables, however the format is not desirable.

#### Question

Is there a way to apply the `optimal column width` setting to all tables in a file?

It would be awesome if I could apply it to all tables in multiple docx files at once.
However, it would already make me very happy if I could automatically format all tables in a single docx file.

Answer (score 1):

The code needs to loop through all tables in the document, select each one and then optimize the selected table.

The following Basic code from Andrew Pitonyak's macro document section 7.2.1 shows how to select a table.

```vb
ThisComponent.getCurrentController().select(oTable)
```

Here is some python code from a project of mine.

```py
    cellsRange = table.getCellRangeByPosition(
        0, 0, endCol, numRows - 1)
    controller.select(cellsRange)
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(
        frame, ".uno:SetOptimalColumnWidth", "", 0, ())
```

There are also ways to loop through a set of documents, so the code can open, optimize, save and close each document. The most difficult part is closing properly without a crash, as closing events can sometimes interrupt each other.

If this is a problem, you may find it easier to open, save and close each by hand, running the macro to optimize all tables in the currently open document. It's also not too hard to loop through all open documents, if you find it more convenient to open multiple files at the same time.